# Controlling learning_rate does not tflearn

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

I'm new with TFLearn.

I was studying this [introduction tutorial](http://tflearn.org/tutorials/quickstart.html) to TFLearn, in which a fixed amount of epochs is set. However I would like to know if it is possible to use the combination *learning_rate* and *accuracy* to determine the end of the network training ...
for example: according to the accuracy decrease or increase the learning_rate ... or according to the accuracy stop the training.

```
# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 6])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Look into http://tflearn.org/models/dnn/ and `best_checkpoint_path` and `best_val_accuracy`. The parameters will save your best checkpoint.

If you want to stop the training, you have to program a callback yourself to stop the training. Here is a nice tutorial about early stopping with TFlearn: http://mckinziebrandon.me/TensorflowNotebooks/2016/11/28/early-stop-solution.html